# Кавычится ли такое название журнала? А слово "спасибо"?

Tags: кавычки

> Интервью тематическому номеру журнала FHM — SEX
>
> Та, которой нужно сказать «спасибо» за наше счастливое детство.

Comment: Вопрос отмечен как «низкокачественный» потому, может быть, что их два?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Сказать спасибо (поблагодарить)**

Встречаются оба варианта, но лучше считать это выражение  устойчивым  сочетанием и не выделять кавычками.

Она недовольство тем, что из лагерей выпустили всех врагов народа, которые вместо того, чтобы **сказать спасибо**, теперь еще требуют каких-то прав и льгот. [Владимир Войнович. Монументальная пропаганда // «Знамя», 2000]

Духовику Клементьеву следовало **сказать спасибо**. [Владимир Орлов. Альтист Данилов (1980)]

2) **Иностранные названия журналов** обычно не выделяют кавычками (они уже и так выделены).

Answer (score 3):

Если название написано латиницей (в том числе если представляет собой инициальную аббревиатуру из латинских букв), кавычки не нужны: газеты Financial Times, Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung; журналы GQ, FHM. ([Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2))

*Спасибо* не кавычится, если употребляется в смысле "слова благодарности":

<Спасибо, неизм. и (разг.) –а; ср. Благодарность; слова благодарности. Примите моё сердечное, искреннее с. И спасиба не сказал. * Из спасибо шубы не сошьёшь (Погов.). ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%20&all=x))